# Passing multiple arrays as parameters to a function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pass a string array to a function, as well as a variable (which I've made into a single element array), but i'm not sure what the format is.

```
Function UpdateMembership ([string[]]$arr,[string[]]$group)
{
write-host $arr[0]
write-host $arr[1]
write-host $Group[0]
}

$OUs = @(
              "test1",
              "test2"
                )
$groupname  = @("group")

UpdateMembership ($Ous, $groupname)

$groupname = @()
$Ous = @()
```

Comment: I didnt understand it correctly. You mean to say that you wish to update the OU and groupname based on the input that you are taking in the function? Then use `for` loop and update it. Or directly call @OU and @Groupname in the updatemembership function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking the function, parameters are **NOT** enclosed in parenthese nor delimited by a comma.

Like you do it, you force **ONE** array to be handed over to the function.

You may use parameter names

```
> UpdateMembership -arr $Ous -group $groupname
test1
test2
group
```

or simply rely on positional order

```
> UpdateMembership $Ous $groupname
test1
test2
group
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function UpdateMembership ([string[]]$arr,[string[]]$group)
{
    write-host $arr[0]
    write-host $arr[1]
    write-host $Group[0]
}

$OUs = @(
    "test1",
    "test2"
)
$groupname  = @("group")

UpdateMembership @Ous @groupname

$groupname = @()
$Ous = @()
```